# Unity: Why is the video player component colour not the same as the original video?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just incase, what i meant is as depicted in the image below. Video is from the video player component and image is from a screenshot of the video opened in VLC. Even in the project folder the video is more red then on the video player component. It's just really weird and wondering if its somehow fixable? I read somewhere about colour space in the player settings and mine is already set to Gamma.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check from the menu `Window>lighting>skybox` that "FOG" is off.

If that doesn't help, I found this answer on the Internet:

> I think that's because you are using directional light or another light to your plane, disable it from your plane with any way, for the
>   dull color, you can try this,
>
> The main idea is make your plane to be like multiply layer to the
>   white space.
>
> Set the material of your plane be more metalic, and smoothness around
>   0.5 (you can play with this) thick the reflection on forward rendering options, next step is make our mirror (plane) reflecting white color.
>   Go to window > lighting and set your skybox material using
>   Sprites-Default, it will make you entire world become white.

Please see if that works for you.

Comment: As for the other answer, im not sure about the plane and material as its a video component. Sorry, i dont understand.